Find the inverse of $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z^2,x-y+z,2x+y-z)$
This question is linked to Prove that the given function is invertible
Find the inverse of $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z^2,x-y+z,2x+y-z)$. I am looking for  an approach to find the inverse of such a 3d function, and not a proof of that such an inverse exists, we can express the function as $(u,v,w)=f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z^2,x-y+z,2x+y-z)$. That gives a system of equations:
$u=x+y+z^2$,
$v=x-y+z$,
$w=2x+y-z$.
Adding the last two together we get $v+w=3x\implies x=\frac{1}{3}(v+w)$ or $v=3x-w$ but I can't get any further, given that quadratic term in  the first equation.

@GerryMyerson done.

@KurtG. hilarious again!! :D

Solving the two last two equations gives the intersection of two planes which is a line.
$$v = x - y + z$$
$$w = 2x  + y - z$$
A vector $\vec s$ and a point $p$ on the intersection of the planes generates this line. Solving this will give you a parametric description of the line
$$x = x_p + \lambda \vec s$$
$$y = y_p + \lambda \vec s$$
$$z = z_p + \lambda \vec s.$$
You can then substitute the above into the equation
$$ u = x + y + z^2$$
which will give a second-degree polynomial equation in $\lambda$ which you can solve.
